# Channel creation fails in "Mirth connect" connected to an Azure DB

Tags: azure-sql-database, hl7, mirth, mirth-connect

I have successfully connected "Mrth Connect 3.5" with an Azure DB. But when i try to create and save a channel i`m getting an internal server error as below from Mirth. [image: Mirth connect error]

Below is the Mirth Connect Server Manager database settings and connection string. I`m confident that this connection string is correct as Mirth Connect Server Manager turns to orange in color when i try connect to the Azure DB using these settings. So what might be causing the error.

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://**.database.windows.net;DatabaseName=**
```

[image: Mirth connect sever manager settings]

Comment: Did you get any solution for this @chamodh?

Comment: no i didn`t. seems to this wasn`t supported at time so i had to create a channels in a local SQL DB

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the above method couple of times. I did not work for me either. The best way usually everyone prefers is to leave the default mirth settings as it is in the server manager, so your screen will look like below

[image]

Inside the Mirth you can create channels and from the channel you can establish the connection to the databases as you like. This method will definitely work. I have tried connecting mydatabase established in AWS server it was working for me. Make sure you open the default port of MSSQL (1433). In case you create a new user and assign the database your port number may change. In that case you this below query in SQL server

```
USE master GO xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N’Server is listening on’ GO
```

To identify the port number in which the database is running, and open that specific port in your cloud system.

Follow this to learn more about the connection string and DB reader in Mirth https://hl7engine.wordpress.com/2017/08/21/mirth-db-reader/

Comment: Hi Viben , Thank you for your response. Unfortunately if i use the default Mirth setting all the channel configuration details will be stored in a local database. But my client`s request is to fully use the azure database and store the channel configuration details also in Azure. Any suggestions !